# Is there a Wattpad public API to retrieve the story 'Reads' and 'Votes' counts?

Tags: api, wattpad

I've looked at the Wattpad API documentation at http://developer.wattpad.com/docs/api but there doesn't seem to be a public API to retrieve a story's 'Reads' and 'Votes' counters.

Currently I'm using a simple bash script with curl and awk to retrieve the counters, but this seems a waste of resources because typical page size appears to be 60K and a JSON response would be much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a direct API for doing what you're looking for, however you can get the data you're looking for indirectly using the story search API.

For example if you hit the following API (with your auth key of course):
`https://api.wattpad.com:443/v4/stories?query=your%20story%20title&limit=1`

you'll get back a JSON payload. The documentation is a little out of date as to what fields you will receive, but you should see voteCount and readCount properties as part of the response.

We're working on getting the documentation updated, as well as possibly providing more API capabilities. Please stay tuned.  Also, please let us know what you end up doing with the API, we're very curious about what people are looking to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggested work around. I'll give this a shot. A friend of mine has started writing stories but was a bit frustrated that the iOS app didn't give the 'Reads' count, and there didn't seem to be a digest email option for Reads/Votes. Currently the little script I have will trigger a [blink1](http://blink1.thingm.com) to show different colors depending on the number of new reads/votes; or send a [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com) notification; or have an [NeTV](http://www.adafruit.com/products/609) show a ticker while watching NetFlix. Polls every 60 seconds.

Comment: I forgot to write that the Prowl notification is going to my friend's AppleWatch.

Comment: amazing timing, if you're friend has an Apple Watch, then they should definite update to our latest iOS app.  It comes with a watch app that specifically gives authors reads and votes for their stories, as well as the number of reads and votes they've received since the last time they checked.  Probably does exactly what they're looking for :-)

Comment: I passed your info on to my friend and his response was that he has to manually launch the Wattpad app on the Apple Watch vs. the near-real-time-instant-gratification of the Prowl "push" notification. The Prowl notification was already giving him the number of new reads/votes since the last update (e.g., "1,234 up 17"). Do you think you'll be adding push notifications, just in case there are other users like my young, story-writing friend who gets a big boost in confidence and self-esteem when the counts go up? :-)

Comment: At this point in time I don't believe we're planning on sending any sort of real-time push notifications for reads. I work on the writer team at Wattpad so I know how much attention writers pay to their stories' stats, the challenge for us is that with well over 100 million stories and billions of reads a month it would require a heavy engineering effort to send notifications for all of them. But hey, you never know...